# How can I handle RAW SOAP responce?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, interceptor

I have this soap handler:

```
@Slf4j
public class ResponseInterceptor implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(out);
            String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
        } catch (SOAPException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But I handle **Requests**. Is there a similar way to handle **Responses**?

EDIT:

I have next task: I need handle all RAW responces from SOAP service, filter it, and send to apache kafka. I do not want to have unmarshaling operation and I want send RAW responce to kafka

EDIT2:

I write interceptor:

```
@Slf4j
public class ResponseInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public ResponseInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_UNMARSHAL);
    }



    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapMessage.writeTo(out);
            String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
            message.getInterceptorChain().abort();
        } catch (SOAPException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But if I call `message.getInterceptorChain().abort();` I get exception in service. But I need just brake this responce and not delivery to web service

Answer (score 2):

CXF interceptors are not "in and of themselves" linked to requests or responses, for at least two reasons :

- Many interceptors can work on both sides (e.g. logging the soap payload)
- There is a symetry of what is to be done on the request/response side of things, with respect to the client/server nature of the app.

So the way CXF works is that interceptors are bound to "chains", which CXF creates and manages at runtime, and which account for all combinations of the above : IN, OUT, IN_FAULT, OUT_FAULT. You can read all about them [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html).

If your current interceptor handles "requests" that means one of two things :

- If your application is a server, then, your interceptor is bound to the "IN" chain
- If your application is a client, then, your interceptor is bound to the "OUT" chain

If you want to handle responses as well as requests, you need to find how/where your custom interceptors are bound to a chain, which is usually in the configuration file in CXF (see : "writing and configuring interceptors" in the abose link).

Many people use CXF with Spring configuration, and therefore, add interceptors at the whole CXF (bus) level like so :

```
<bean id="MyInterceptor" class="demo.interceptor.MyInterceptor"/>
<!-- We are adding the interceptors to the bus as we will have only one endpoint/service/bus. -->
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="MyInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="MyInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

But it can also be done at the enpoint level.

Further reading : [How to catch any exceptions in a SOAP webservice method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180650/how-to-catch-any-exceptions-in-a-soap-webservice-method/25182154#25182154)

### Accessing the contents before (un)marshalling

I could expand a lot, but I suggest you look at the [`org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor`](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingInInterceptor.java) (or the respective one for "Out" messages), they are as good an example as you can see of "how to access the raw content without breaking anything".

Comment: Thanks for the good example. But I know this (But the answer is still very useful). I'll try to clarify and maybe you can help me. I need process soap responces without unmarshlling. I send request by CXF and I need get responce RAW and not start unmarshalling.

Comment: Got it. You shoul edit your question to clarify this! May I ask what is your purpose (e.g. log the whole message ?)

Comment: Ok I will eddit question. I have microservice with scheduller. This scheduller send requests to SOAP service and get responces. I want filter responces and send needed to kafka (without unmarshalling).

Comment: I add some additions to questions. Look it please

Comment: Hello, so as to help further readers finding their way in the site, please, do not ask several questions which are not related in the same question here. You will get more people to look into your questions, and better answers, if you do not hide a question (about marhsalling) inside another question (about activating interceptors in chain), see ? Please open another question with your other specific issues.